# MouseClick and MoveTo event is not working on the 2nd Part that spawned

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm working on a project that the player clicks on an object and it walks over to it, wait a second, then the object is removed from the game and points update on the leaderboard. The problem is it only works on the first round. The 2nd time, the new part spawned and it does have the ClickDetector as its child, but it does not function.

```
local flowers = game.ReplicatedStorage.Flowers.level1:GetChildren()
local selection = math.random(1,#flowers)
local Clone = flowers[selection]:Clone()

local ClickDetector = Instance.new("ClickDetector")
ClickDetector.Parent = Clone
ClickDetector.MaxActivationDistance = 500

local spawners = workspace.Spawners.level1:GetChildren()
local spawnSelection = math.random(1,#spawners)
local spawner = spawners[spawnSelection]

while true do

    wait(1)
    if Clone.Parent == nil then
        Clone.Parent = workspace.Flowers.level1
        Clone.CFrame = spawner.CFrame + Vector3.new(math.random(-5,5),1,math.random(-5,5))
        print("Clone added")

        ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(playerWhoClicked)
            playerWhoClicked.Character.Humanoid:MoveTo(Clone.Position,Clone)
            print("clicked")

            wait(1)

            Clone:Remove()
            print("Clone removed")

            local flowerValue = playerWhoClicked.leaderstats.Flowers
            local coinsValue = playerWhoClicked.leaderstats.Coins
            flowerValue.Value = flowerValue.Value + 1
            coinsValue.Value = coinsValue.Value + 5
        end)
    end

end
```

There are no error messages on output. Just that on the new spawned part, "clicked" is not printing.

Comment: What does Clone:Remove() do? If it doesn't set Clone.Parent to nil then the issue is that the body of the if statement isn't run the second and subsequent times.

Comment: Clone:Remove() removes the part that was cloned from the ReplicatedStorage out of the game so it's parent doesn't exist anymore. That makes the game to clone a new part from ReplicatedStorage back into the game. That's why the old part disappears then a new part appears with ClickDetector as its child. The original part in ReplicatedStorage do not have a ClickDetector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the function in the ClickDetector is using a reference to Clone, and when Clone is destroyed, it doesn't exist anymore. Your code would work if it simply unparented the object from the world rather than destroyed it.

```
-- choose a random flower and clone it
local flowers = game.ReplicatedStorage.Flowers.level1:GetChildren()
local selection = math.random(1,#flowers)
local Clone = flowers[selection]:Clone()

-- configure a click detector into the cloned flower
local ClickDetector = Instance.new("ClickDetector")
ClickDetector.Parent = Clone
ClickDetector.MaxActivationDistance = 500
ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(playerWhoClicked)
    -- when a player clicks on the flower, move the player over to it
    playerWhoClicked.Character.Humanoid:MoveTo(Clone.Position,Clone)
    print("clicked")

    -- remove the cloned flower from the workspace, but don't destroy it
    wait(1)
    Clone.Parent = nil -- << simply hide it from the world

    -- award the player with some points
    local flowerValue = playerWhoClicked.leaderstats.Flowers
    local coinsValue = playerWhoClicked.leaderstats.Coins
    flowerValue.Value = flowerValue.Value + 1
    coinsValue.Value = coinsValue.Value + 5
end)

-- choose a random spawn location
local spawners = workspace.Spawners.level1:GetChildren()
local spawnSelection = math.random(1,#spawners)
local spawner = spawners[spawnSelection]

-- begin a loop to place the flower into the world
while true do

    wait(1)
    -- if the flower isn't visible, place it near a specific location
    if Clone.Parent == nil then
        Clone.Parent = workspace.Flowers.level1
        Clone.CFrame = spawner.CFrame + Vector3.new(math.random(-5,5),1,math.random(-5,5))
        print("Clone added into the world")

        -- now wait for a player to click on it and unparent it.
        -- this case will come back around a second later, and it will be added back in.
    end

end
```

This way, you don't have to worry about the second or third spawning of the flower, because there will only ever be one flower.

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked like a charm. While waiting for someone to help me find the problem in the script, I made an alternative script by using the part directly in Workspace instead of cloning it from ReplicatedStorage, and altering its Transparency and debounce before reappearing again. I really like your Clone.Parent = nil. I didn't know about that other than either Remove() or Destroy(). I will continue to use *.Parent = nil in the future.

Comment: I added a wait for the player to reach the part and playing an animation before making it disappear and now it's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work, it was hard to understand your question, but I think what your saying is that the clone wont appear after you click again. Well did this work? Also, you don't need to have the click event inside the loop, and to make a clone every time the player clicks, inside the click function you make a clone of the Clone variable.

```
local flowers = game.ReplicatedStorage.Flowers.level1:GetChildren()
local selection = math.random(1,#flowers)
local Clone = flowers[selection]:Clone()

local ClickDetector = Instance.new("ClickDetector")
ClickDetector.Parent = Clone
ClickDetector.MaxActivationDistance = 500

local spawners = workspace.Spawners.level1:GetChildren()
local spawnSelection = math.random(1,#spawners)
local spawner = spawners[spawnSelection]

while true do

    wait(1)
    if Clone.Parent == nil then
        Clone.Parent = workspace.Flowers.level1
        Clone.CFrame = spawner.CFrame + Vector3.new(math.random(-5,5),1,math.random(-5,5))
        print("Clone added")
    end

end
ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(playerWhoClicked)
    _clone = Clone:Clone()
    playerWhoClicked.Character.Humanoid:MoveTo(_clone.Position,_clone)
    print("clicked")

    wait(1)

    _clone:Destroy()
    print("_clone removed")

    local flowerValue = playerWhoClicked.leaderstats.Flowers
    local coinsValue = playerWhoClicked.leaderstats.Coins
    flowerValue.Value = flowerValue.Value + 1
    coinsValue.Value = coinsValue.Value + 5
end)
```

Comment: That was my initial trial. Making the loop regeneration and the ClickDetector separate, also I tried putting them into separate server scripts.

Comment: The clone did appear and it also have a ClickDetector in it. Hovering over it does show the ClickDetector icon, but clicking it doesn't do what it supposed to do. It works only the first time when player first enter the game. After player clicks on it and it disappears and reappears, the clickdetector doesn't work when it reappears.

Comment: This example won't work because the while loop prevents the code from ever reaching the ClickDetector.MouseClick connection. The clone will appear in the world with a ClickDetector, but nothing will happen when you click on it. The while loop must be at the end.

Comment: Just make the loop a coroutine.